# Angular Dependecies are not Refelcted in package.json

Tags: angular

In my angular project when i install any package or module it is notgetting reflected into pakcage.json

my command is:-

```
  npm install -save bootstrap@4.0.0
```

i also tried with --save -d option but it is not working 
Please suggest me way to do it

Comment: What version of node and npm are you running?

Comment: npm :-5.6.0 and node :-8.9.4

Answer (score 1):

You need `--`:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0
```

or `-S` for dependencies and `-D` for dev-dependencies:

```
npm install -S bootstrap@4.0.0
```

---

So, it is either `--save` or `-S` and either `--save-dev` or `-D`.

Comment: so the command will be  npm install -D bootstrap@4.0.0 but it does not include package in package.json

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0

npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0 --global
```

To be more effectly